# JBoss access log duration

Tags: http, jboss, tcp

For JBoss's AccessLogValve, we have activated the optional field,

> - %D - Time taken to process the request, in millis

This has been super-valuable in showing us which responses took the most time.  I now need details on how this field is calculated.  Specifically, when does JBoss stop the "time taken to process..." clock?  For example, does JBoss stop it when the [first segment of the] response is given to the TCP/IP stack to transmit to the client?  Or when the client sends an [ACK] following the last segment?  Or when a network timeout occurs?

Knowing this will help me find root causes for some crazy-long response times in our production access logs.

Comment: I think what you are after is a java profiler tool like JProfiler, DynaTrace, etc. Those tools will help you break down time spent in the request.